# Start making requests after the user types 3 or more characters

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I need to start loading the items after the user types 3 or more characters.

```
$('#search-name').selectize({
    valueField: 'x',        
    searchField: 'x',       
    options: [],
    create: false,

    render: {
        option: function (item, escape) {
            return '<div>' + item.name + '</div>';
        }
    },

    load: function (query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',                
            url: 'an url', 
            error: function () {
                callback();
            },
            success: function (res) {
                callback(res.names.slice(0, 10));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I didn't find anything helpful in documentation. **onChange** is not helpful in my case.

Comment: Why is onchange not helpful? It sounds like it's exactly what you need... or keydown/keypress/keyup maybe?

Comment: Can you not just change `if (!query.length)` to `if (query.length < 3)`

Comment: @George but doesn't the callback on run once on load? So what if the user types three characters after this check has run?